# concat() shown as varbinary in hex format in squirrel sql instead of plain text

Tags: mysql, squirrel-sql

How to prevent Squirrel SQL to show `concat()` of int data types as varbinary in hex format instead of plain text?

For example, `SELECT CONCAT(1,2)` shows the hex notation `3132` instead of `"12"` ...

Looking at the MetaData result tab shows that the resulting column type is `VARBINARY`. How can I force it to be plain text?

Comment: how about `concat (cast 1 as char,cast 2 as char)` ?

Comment: Yes this returns `"12"`, but your syntax is wrong. It's select `concat(cast( 1 as char),cast(2 as char))`. However I was looking for a more persistent and less syntax-intensive solution, since a simple `select concat(1,2)` returns in plain text in mysql command-line.

Comment: I have also faced the same issue, but not resolved using any of above comments. When used the same query with another client with mysql it worked correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Use the CAST command, for example:

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(1,2) AS CHAR)
```